# Numerical Integral of an image?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, signal-processing, image-processing

I am currently trying to implement the method described in [this paper](http://www.imp.uni-erlangen.de/pdfs/EDEC_MedPhys%202007.pdf). In short we have a system of the form $a=B\times c$. Where $a_i = \int d^3r \space w(r)f_i(r)t(r)  $ and $B_{ij} = \int d^3r \space w(r)f_i(r)f_j(r)$. The solution is given by $c = B^{-1}a$. In this case $w,t,f_i$ are volumes, specifically a sequence of images obtained from an x-ray simulation. When I solve these integrals using matlab's trapz function I get a poorly-conditioned $B$ matrix. Is there any other way to integrate this type of data (images)? Or a different way to calculate my $a$ and $B$ terms?

Comment: You may try applying regularization to your problem, like [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) for example

Comment: I will give this a try and report. However wouldn't the value used in the regularization affect my final result?

Comment: Sure, but regularization is something you need to do if your problem has noise and is badly scaled. Otherwise your solution will be far from what you wanted

Comment: Indeed, regularization worked. Thank you very much.